# How to know if UIScrollView touches on top scrollView intersects with a CGPoint of another View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uitouch

I have 2 UIScrollView. They are not subviews of each other. One is just sitting above the other as an overlay, which was used to get this effect:

[image]

Now, I have a `UIButton` on the 2nd ScrollView (the one sitting below).
I cannot tap on this button because the top scroll view is capturing all the touches.

So here is what I am trying to accomplish. But I'm stuck.

1. I put a UITapGestureRecognizer recognized on the UIScrollView
2. I want to convert the CGPoint of the tap and translate it over to a position on the 2nd scrollView
3. If the point intersects with the position of the UIButton on the 2nd UIScrollView, then I'll just print a message.

Here is my code. Please help me what's wrong with it:

```
@IBAction func bufferviewCliked (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // First I try to get the point of the object clicked inside as a point on
    // the main self.view
    let locationInMainView = sender.location(in: self.view)

    // Next I try to convert that point, into a point on my backgroundScrollView
    let touchPointInSecondView = self.view.convert(locationInMainView, from: backGround)

    // If the point intersects with the point on the UIButton in the backgroundScrollView
    // Then print hi
    if followButton.frame.contains(touchPointInSecondView) {
        print("HI")
    }
}
```

The problem is my point coordinates are wrong and I'm not sure if I used the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the locationInView from button

```
@IBAction func bufferviewCliked (sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   let location = sender.location(in: followButton)

   // If the point intersects with the point on the UIButton in the backgroundScrollView
   // Then print hi
   if followButton.bounds.contains(location) {
        print("HI")
   }
}
```